# How to calculate how many bit sequences of size n with k bits set and c changes of bit values exist?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics, bit, computation

We know that calculating the number of n-length bit sequences with k bits set is equal to *C(n,k)=n!/(k!*(n-k)!)*.

But I've recently asked myself how can you think about this problem once another condition is set: The number of bit value changes. For instance, for *n*=4 and *k*=2 we have 6 solutions:

1-0011

2-0101

3-0110

4-1001

5-1010

6-1100

Now suppose we only want to get the sequences with two changes in bit values. Now there are only two solutions:

1-0110 (begins with 0, changes to 1, than changes to 0 after).
2-1001 (begins with 1, changes to 0, than changes to 1 after).

How can I quickly calculate the number of solutions(without generating every combination and counting)? I think one could count the initial bit as a change without changing the answer too much, so feel free to do it.

Extra question: Given a combination with *k* bits set and *c* number of bit changes, what is the quickest way to generate the next combination with the same amount of *k* bits set and *c* number of bit changes?

Comment: With two bit changes, the minimum sequences are: 101 and 010. It's then a matter of distributing the excess 1's and 0's. For example, take `n=10  k=4  c=2`. Starting with 101, there are two excess 1's and five excess 0's. There's only one place to put the 0's. The excess 1's can be placed three different ways zero at the beginning and two at the end, or one and one, or two at the beginning and one at the end. So there are only three possibilities starting from 101: 1000000111, 1100000011, 1110000001.

Comment: This is not really a programming problem, no?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [balls-and-urns](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Ball-and-urn) problem. You start with a sequence of alternating `0`s and `1`s with the required number of bit changes, and then you place the remaining `0`s and `1`s into the urns.

Example: `n=20`, `k=8`, `c=4`.

Consider the case where the bistring starts with `0`. Start with `(c+1)` alternating bits, to get your `c` changes:

```
01010
```

At this point you still need to place 9 `0`s and 6 `1`s. Let's place the `0`s first. How many ways can we place the 9 remaining `0`s, without adding any bit changes? There are 3 "urns" to place the "balls" (`0`s):

```
0 ... 1 0 ... 1 0 ...
   ^       ^       ^
```

There are `(9+3-1) choose 3` ways of placing 9 balls into 3 urns.

Once the `0`s are placed, we also need to place the `1`s. By similar reasoning, we have 6 balls (`1`s) to place in 2 urns, which can be done in `(6+2-1) choose 2` ways.

Since the arrangement of `0`s and `1`s are independent, we multiply the results: there are `((9+3-1) choose 3) * ((6+2-1) choose 2)` ways for a length-20 bitstring with 8 `1`s to have 4 bit changes, *assuming you start with `0`*.

You still need to add the remaining case (starting with `1`, so the first step results in `10101`), which can be solved in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a row of `n` indistinguishable objects, say red balls. How many ways can we divide them into `k` non-empty groups? That's pretty easy, right? The first group starts with the first object, and every other group has to start at some different object. So we can construct a partition by choosing the first object and `k-1` of the `n-1` remaining objects, which we can do in `C(n-1, k-1)` different ways.

Now suppose we have another row of `m` indistinguishable objects, say blue balls, and we want to divide them into `j` groups. But that's exactly the same problem, and the solution must be `C(m-1, j-1)`.

OK, now suppose we want to construct a row of objects, of which `n` are red and `m` are blue, in which there are a total of `c` groups alternating between red and blue. Now, there are two possibilities:

1. The row will start with a red ball. If `c` is even, then there will be `c/2` red groups interleaved with `c/2` blue groups. If `c` is odd, there will be one more red group than blue group, so there will be `ceil(c/2)` red groups and `floor(c/2)` blue groups. (If `c` is even then both `floor(c/2)` and `ceil(c/2)` are exactly `c/2`. So we can use the floor and ceil formulas in both cases.)

   In any event, we can divide the red balls into groups and the blue balls into groups independently, and then interleave them. So there are `C(n - 1, ceil(c/2) - 1) × C(m - 1, floor(c/2) - 1)` possible arrangements.
2. The row will start with a blue ball. Exactly the same analysis applies, except that `n` and `m` are reversed.

So the total number of arrangements is:

```
C(n - 1, ceil(c/2) - 1) × C(m - 1, floor(c/2) - 1) +
C(n - 1, floor(c/2) - 1) × C(m - 1, ceil(c/2) - 1)
```

This is just a rewriting of your problem, which had `k` ones and `n-k` zeros, with `c-1` transitions (which leads to `c` groups). I'll leave the remaining algebra step to the reader (as well as the simplification for odd group counts).

Comment: This is exactly what I came to develop after thinking until now. For odd c, is there any possible further simplification better than 2*C(n-1,c/2-1)*C(m-1,c/2-1)?

Comment: @eduard: compute the smaller binomial first, which avoids doing the same multiplications twice